# listing files of a specific date and writing to another file in perl

Tags: perl, date

I have a list of *.DTA* files with below dates.

```
Jun 26 02:53 fs261803.DTA
Jun 26 02:54 fs261804.DTA
Jun 26 02:56 fs261805.DTA
Jun 26 03:25 fs261865.DTA
Jun 26 03:27 fs261869.DTA
Jun 27 03:21 fs271865.DTA
Jun 27 03:23 fs271869.DTA
Jun 28 03:23 fs281865.DTA
Jun 28 03:25 fs281869.DTA
Jun 29 03:21 fs291865.DTA
Jun 29 03:23 fs291869.DTA
Jun 29 03:54 fs291803.DTA
```

I want to write all *jun 29* files data's into one file. I have the logic to combine multiple files into one. Below is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $start_pos = 0;
my $data_len  = 15;
my $pad_len   = 54;

my $dir = ".";
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die "Cannot open directory: $dir!\n";
my @files = readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);
open my $out, ">>output.trns" or die "Cannot open output.trns!\n";

foreach my $file (@files)
{
    if($file =~ /DTA$/)
        #if ($file=`ls -rlt *.DTA` )
    {
        #print "$file\n";
        open my $in, "<$file" or die "Cannot open $file!\n";
        while (<$in>) {
        say $out ' ' x $pad_len, substr($_, $start_pos, $data_len);
        }

        close $in;
        }
}
close $out;
```

In this code I can combine all the *.DTA* files into one. But I need to combine only *Jun 29* files to create one new file. Can anyone help me out in `perl`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to compare the file's timestamps (presumably the modification time), you need to `stat()` each file and compare the corresponding year, month, and day. Here's an example that hard-codes a filter for 2018-06-29:

```
next unless $file =~ /DTA$/;
my $fullpath = $dir . "/" . $file;
my $wantedyear=2018;
my $wantedmonth=5; ## zero-based
my $wantedday=29;
my $mtime=(stat $fullpath)[9];
my $fileyear=(localtime($mtime))[5] + 1900;
next unless $fileyear == $wantedyear;
my $filemonth=(localtime($mtime))[4];
next unless $filemonth == $wantedmonth;
my $fileday=(localtime($mtime))[3];
next unless $fileday == $wantedday;
```